# XSD Validation Error in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, xsd, spring-data

does anybody have an solution for the invalid spring-data-elasticsearch.xsd file ?

http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd

I try to load this xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd">

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="ElasticSearchClient" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="ElasticSearchClient" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But im getting these error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd; lineNumber: 40; columnNumber: 116; s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'source' in element 'documentation': cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1.
```

I found some questions about it, but nobody have an solution for that. And it's not possible to create a bug issue at the GitHub Project.

Thanks
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to use the xsd without problems. because of that, i create a configuration bean for that.

```
package org.example;

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;

@Configuration
class ElasticsearchConfiguration
{   
    @Bean(name="elasticsearchTemplate")
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate()
    {
        Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300));       
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

that works for me ....

Marcel